# Javascript Quiz adding input type to javascript

Tags: javascript

Im creating a random questions quiz and i want to add different type of inputs but dont know how. Yes I know how to in the HTML but I want to add it to the array of questions.

How do I add radio button, text input or image to the following code?

```
 const myQuestions = [
{
    question: "What is the name of the actor The Rock?",
        answers: [
            { text: 'Dwayne Johnson', correct: true },
            { text: 'Paul Walker', correct: false },
            { text: 'Vin Diesel', correct: false },
            { text: 'Tyrese Gibson', correct: false }

        ]
    }
```

];

Here. is how Im using the array.

```
function showQuestion(question) {
questionsElements.innerText = question.question;
console.log(question.question);

question.answers.forEach(answer => {
    const button = document.createElement("radio");
    button.innerText = answer.text;
    
    button.classList.add('radio');  
    if (answer.correct) {
        button.dataset.correct = answer.correct;
    }

    button.addEventListener("click", selectAnswer);
    answerButtons.appendChild(button);
})
```

}

Comment: How about adding property to the object- `{ question: '..', inputType: '..', answers: [..] }`

Comment: @ShivamSingla can you show me a quick code example how to implement it?

Comment: Please paste the code, how you are using `myQuestions` array.

Comment: Now I am confused. What do you mean by "different type of inputs"?

Comment: @ShivamSingla Ok so I want one question to show an image and ask "Who is this" , one question to get the user to text the answer and the last option is uading radio buttons

Comment: Please add other types of questions too, and code how you are distinguishing them.